# MS Access: How to strip time off a date field?

Tags: ms-access

For example a value in a field might be

```
8/5/2010 11:18:22 AM
```

And I want to strip it down to

```
8/5/2010
```

It is a Date/Time field format

Comment: When storing or when retrieving? Is this in an Access application, or through ODBC.OLEDB?

Comment: Retrieving. I am currently making a Select query in Design View that involves a table which has this date field

Comment: what langauge do you want? do you want it in a new field? do you want it to change the existing field?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Solved the issue using DateValue()

Answer (score 0):

`Time` is a decimal place so if you don't want time then update the field using:

```
round(number,NumDigitsAfterDecimal as long)
```

Comment: Beware `Round()` will advance the date for times after midday, eg `Round(#3/28/2021 13:00#, 0)` returns `3/29/2021`